# How to print a element of list in a particular format

Tags: java

I am trying to print a list object that contains string elements in following format
('string1','string2','string3',..)

I want to use the above format in my sql query

Comment: unclear what you want. May be example would help.

Comment: What is the problem ? if you want that you could make a loop with the wanted formatting into a String ...

Comment: What format? Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("item1");
    list.add("item2");
    list.add("item3");
    list.add("item4");
    System.out.println(list.toString().replace("[", "('").replace("]", "')").replace(", ", "', '"));
```

This will fail badly if your `String`s contain `[` or `]` or `,`
The safe way of doing this will be using a loop:

```
    String result = "(";
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
            result += ",";
        }
        result += "'" + list.get(i) + "'";
    }
    result += ")";
    System.out.println(result);
```